# Retrieve data from database to label using SqldataReader

Tags: asp.net

I'm writting code in asp.net.. I need to print question from database into label and options from same database table to Radiobutton.  I have used sqldataReader in the following code but, the problem is it print only One question repeatedly from database not printing next question in the next label.

```
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Questable1 ", connection);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();
            Label1.Text = reader["Ques"].ToString();
            RadioButton1.Text = reader["Option1"].ToString();
            RadioButton2.Text = reader["Option2"].ToString();
            RadioButton3.Text = reader["Option3"].ToString();
            RadioButton4.Text = reader["Option4"].ToString();

            Label2.Text = reader["Ques"].ToString();
            RadioButton5.Text = reader["Option1"].ToString();
            RadioButton6.Text = reader["Option2"].ToString();
            RadioButton7.Text = reader["Option3"].ToString();
            RadioButton8.Text = reader["Option4"].ToString();

            connection.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your logic looks confusing.So you already know the number of questions in the table? will they always be the same? You will have to add labels manually for all the questions.I prefer using a gridview in this case. Plus, you are not looping around the reader so that the whoe table gets displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Datareader will be holding all the rows from the result set.

you can iterate through it as follows...

```
connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Questable1 ", connection);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader.Read())
{
//write your logic bind questions
           // Label1.Text = reader["Ques"].ToString();
}
```

But as @MukeshPanwar mentioned you need to be more clear.
As per my understanding looks like your question and answer are in the same resultant table and hence question should be repeating. you have sort it out before binding questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

use listview to retrieve data with your own layout, even radiobutton. then set the text of radiobutton like this in aspx:

```
<%# Eval("Field_name_of_your_database") %>
```

then to bind data, same as the gridview or detailedview. just return dataset, then datasource then databind.